Trying to send an IR signal but LIRC and pigpod doesnt seem to work on RPI5 (Debian Bookworm)
Looking for any way to send an IR signal from a pi 5 through the GPIO pins ive been able to capture the info IR signals I need to send out but the transmitter does not work on PI5. Used LIRC for PI4 and it works fine need help pls.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

You can transmit infrared signals using an IR LED attached to the GPIO. You don't need LIRC, which has been superseded by Linux kernel upgrades.
See this article by Gordon Turner https://blog.gordonturner.com/2020/06/10/raspberry-pi-ir-transmitter/
(I know we discourage link-only answers, but it is not easy to summarize and not fair to copy everything.)
